# How to detect the term color support inside of a emacsclient session?

Tags: frames, emacsclient, themes, terminal-emacs, colors

I run a emacs daemon on boot as a OpenRC service without info about terminals. When I plug a different terminal on emacsclient so, I don't have env variables instead that was generated inside of emacs or defined on service config. Beyond that, I got different behaviors on face colors of my theme because on each terminal will have different color support. For instance, running `emacsclient` through the `xfce4-terminal` inside of a `tmux` session I got:

[image: xfce4-terminal]

Plugging the same tmux session on `uxterm` or running without X, I got instead:

[image: xterm]

(is the same emacsclient session, so is the same frame for both because `tmux`)

My wish is: modify the frame face colors only if I don't have a good color support on terminal, which happens on my case with xterm on running without X (console mode C-M-F{1,9}). I want do that because the face background colors for `helm-selection` and `region` is just black (I can't see they on xterm and this is pretty bad for usage).

For now I'm just change the face colors on frame creation for non-X sessions to `red`, like terminal sessions through this function: [setup-terminal-session](https://github.com/ryukinix/dotfiles/blob/3c5a35bcee03de571ba88c2f5e508bc428b30a10/.emacs.d/personal/hooks.el#L102).
But this change even the behavior inside of `xfce4-terminal` (which runs pretty fine because the good color support) and is unecessary.

Maybe I can fix the behavior of `xterm` forcing a type of color support on config through `.Xdefaults` or `.Xresources` file, but and the case of running emacs without X? I don't have full color support on that. So seems a kind of limitation here on a simple thing.

Anyway, my question is (again): there is a way to detect the color support of terminal inside of emacsclient without relying on ENV variables? I just don't understand how `termcap` and `terminfo` works reading the docs, would be nice a clarification on that. Thanks.

Comment: Is `tmux` a necessary part of this set-up? I don't use it myself or know much about it, but it does seem like an added layer of complication here. Emacs has *some* terminal-local capabilities, but that tends to be tied to frames, and here you are sharing a single frame amongst multiple terminals. Given that you're using emacsclient anyhow, you might find that *not* using tmux is better.

Comment: I have the same problem using tmux or not. Using tmux on the example just happened because is pretty integrated on my personal setup. The problem remains not using tmux. I always used emacsclient without tmux and I had that problem before, now is not different. Tmux for me just keep things more easily, actually. Sorry if was confuse to you, but this is pretty unrelated to the problem :/

Comment: I know if I can fix the local frame variable will change the frame, so  I'll change the behavior of the another tmux client which is attached to this same frame. But this not matter if at least I can detect the term color on frame creation (to decide or not change  the theme)

Comment: Maybe have a look at the `tty-color.el` commentary, and the various `tty-*` functions and variables.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that! The name give to me some hope. I'll look :)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't found any particular useful thing for detecting color support on that file, sorry. Reading `tty-color.el` seems is a more a kind of color X simulation for `tty` related to color transformation, pretty unrelated to color support of terminals (though the misleading name). By another hand, this is file defined at `term/tty-color.el`, which directory `term` has a lot of scripts for supporting terminals. I saw interesting things on `term/xterm.el`, however they rely on env variables... so sad. Maybe I need change my approach, as that simple seems not possible.

Comment: I really don't know what manner of "support" you are trying to detect, but I thought you would have found what you needed. e.g. `(tty-display-color-cells)` returns the number of colours available in a terminal-based frame. `(tty-color-alist)` similarly returns data on the actual colours. I presume they work as advertised. Perhaps you could update the question with what you are *specifically* looking for?

Comment: Alternatively, maybe you are *actually* looking for the in-built `M-x customize-face` support for different display types? Select "For All Kinds of Display" on the "State" button, and then insert a new entry and select "specific display" on the "Display" button, and then select "Type" and "TTY" and other attributes as appropriate...

Comment: `(tty-display-color-cells)` return the same number of colors on `xfce4-terminal`, `uxterm` and console mode on session without X. 256. So I think this is unrelated thing, or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Well... for me the question is pretty straightfoward, how much colors the terminal on the emacsclient is running can represent, if is truecolor or not... sorry if seems confuse, but I don't get it.

Comment: Your idea with `customize-face` is pretty close what I want to do, but the problem is that both terminals are considered TTY :/, but I want to change only the one which don't have a good color support (like that terminals which cannot display gray colors and etc). I can set it for TTY and will not mess-up at least the gui sessions, but will change unnecessary the `xfce4-terminal` session which works fine. I mean.. I want to change the colors of the `face` `helm-selection` and `region` to `red` only for for terminals which doesn't display grays: `xterm` and console mode.

Comment: But I don't get as `(tty-display-color-cells)` can have the same number of colors even running on different terminals which different behaviors... Seems that function is what I want, but doesn't works as I expected for some weird reason. `tmux` fault?

Comment: FUCK! (sorry) is `tmux` fault.

Comment: The problem was that `tmux` on my setup are forcing `TERM` to be `xterm-256`, so on inside of emacs `(tty-display-colors-cells)` seems that (again) that function rely on env variables, but at least I have that on terminal session. The mainly problem now is that even with `TERM=xterm-256` I cannot see gray colors on `xterm`... I don't understand that. And don't setting for tmux that, neither `xfce4-terminal` works too. It's just a giant mess, hard to find someone to blame it. So the problem is on my setup and this question was answered. You should add `(tty-display-color-cells)` as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option for customizing faces on a per-terminal-type basis is supported directly in the customize UI:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-face` <kbd>RET</kbd> *face* <kbd>RET</kbd>
- Using the "State" button, select "For All Kinds of Displays"
- INSert a new entry
- Using the "Display" button, select "specific display"
- Select "Type" and "TTY" and other criteria as appropriate...
- e.g. "Class" (color, grayscale, or monochrome); and "Minimum number of colors"

---

To ask Emacs about terminal colour support from elisp, there are a variety of `tty-*` functions and variables, which you can inspect via:
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `apropos` <kbd>RET</kbd> `^tty` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Of particular note:

- The `tty-display-color-cells` function returns the number of colours available in a given terminal (defaulting to the terminal for the current frame).
- The `tty-color-alist` function similarly returns data on the individual colours.

---

When `tmux` is being used, it sounds like Emacs will see the terminal type that `tmux` advertises; so establishing the terminal *behind* `tmux` may require other techniques.

Manoel Vilela recommends:

- Verify that the `TERM` environment variable is set correctly.
- Run `tmux` with `tmux -2` to force 256 colour support, as described in the [tmux manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux).

Comment: Really complete answer. I'm modifying my setup to working `tmux` as well, but this helped a lot.